# tuProlog: how to make dynamic procedures?

Tags: prolog, tuprolog

tuProlog is a light version of prolog but does it support dynamic procedures? I read manual and explore other sources but could not find any information.

If there is maybe other way to make dynamic procedure in tuProlog.

in swi-prolog we have: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=dynamic/1

I want to make something similar but in tuProlog.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: How can I provide something that I dont know if exist.

Comment: What happens when you try to execute `asserta(hello(world)).`? This might be enough to create the dynamic predicate `hello/1`. It's also enough in SWI-Prolog, the `dyamic/1` directive is not required.

Comment: Maybe link the manual you read? As @IsabelleNewbie noted, as long as assert* and retract* predicates are available, you have already got dynamic predicates (procedures?)